# What is the architecture of a website like Shopify?

Tags: javascript, meteor, web, shopify, online-store

I am reading about software architecture of different websites/web application. I know this question might be a bit general but any hints would be really appreciated.

Let's say we know how a single online shop works, how do we expand it to a platform like Shopify where people can create their own shops and then deploy it on the web?

Do you think developing such a platform is doable with a full-stack framework such as MeteorJS ?

Thank you so much,
Amir

Comment: See their stack: https://stackshare.io/shopify/shopify

Answer (score 1):

I would read documentation of existing and working APIs.

For example, from Ecommerce APIs like EBay API you can construct shipping, product, offer, and payment models.

You should also use your own reasoning to create such models, something like: "Ok, so I need to view products, with description, price and images, so an initial model of product would be: `{ description, priceAmount, priceCurrency, image1Url, image2Url, ...}`" , and so on.

In short, create a model for each aspect of your website.